# Consecutive identical "printf" calls produce different output

Tags: c, io, double, printf

I call printf function consecutively and first printf writes what it must write, second printf just writes invalid values and I guess some errors.

Type of "LOC" is defined by me and variable "i" doesn't change after callings.
I checked double for any discrepancy between printf and values I give it.

```
i=2;
printf("x = %f,y = %f,z = %f\n",(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].X,(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].Y,(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].Z); /* Prints perfectly */
printf("x = %f,y = %f,z = %f\n",(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].X,(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].Y,(*LOC)[0].ProjectionPoints[i].Z); /* Shows some errors and values are "0" */
```

First printf writes

```
x = -10.000000,y = -8.000000,z = -10.000000
```

Second printf writes

```
x = 0.000000,y = 0.000000,z = -1.#QNAN0
```

Even defining variables as `const` isn't change anything.

My compiler is: `MS Visual C++ 2012`

After I read comments;

```
typedef struct {
P3C_Point *ProjectionPoints;
uint Distance,LayerID,NumberOfPoints,ModelID;} P3C_LayerOnCurtain;
/* and */
P3C_LayerOnCurtain **LOC = P3C_Compile(Stream);
/* when I try printf in P3C_Compile it has no problems */
```

I made test before I return value, in function produces "LOC" is printf perfectly.

Answer/Solution;

```
 P3C_LayerOnCurtain *LOC = *P3C_Compile(Stream);
```

Comment: Cab you construct a test case?

Comment: How are X, Y, Z declared?

Comment: (could you show us also the definition of LOC?)

Comment: I did, function gives it writes values perfectly

Comment: You'll have to show us more code than this. Where is LOC declared,and how are the arrays allocated? I suspect you're reading from uninitialized or unallocated memory.

Comment: P3C_Point is a struct too?

Comment: Please construct a minimum test case and put the **complete** source in your question.

Comment: show how you alloc **LOC and ProjectionPoints

Comment: The problem is almost certainly as Medinoc hypothesized; you've returned LOC from a function, but the first call to `printf()` reuses the space LOC points at for its own purposes because you returned a local variable from the function where you returned LOC.  You need to show us enough of `P3C_Compile()` to show how the return value is allocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable cause would be that `LOC` or `(*LOC[0].ProjectionPoints)` are pointers to a local variable of a function that returned them.

If so, they would be overwritten by `printf`'s local variables.

Comment: are all local variables write in same adress?

Comment: Local variables are, for all intents and purposes, destroyed when the function returns. Any subsequent function call will overwrite that space with its own local variables. "same address" is a bit of a misnomer, because local variables can have different sizes.

Comment: On a classic x86 architecture, local variables are stored on the stack: They are "pushed" when created and "popped" when destroyed. Function calls also use the stack to store the return address, so functions with no local variables and lots of nested calls would overwrite local variables as well.